# If and else condition inside success in ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

As the title says I want to run the if and else inside the success condition in Ajax, For example after running the Ajax and sees that there is a record it will go to success then inside the success it must look for the "if statement"  and display the alert inside the "if statement" if the statement is true but instead it always display the "else statement" with the alert('no') inside of it, even if there is a record, Thank you

```
<script>
function renderAttendees(id)
        {
            ///$("#attendeesContent").empty();
            var dataString = { "id": id };
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: server+'webservice/crm/viewAttendeesDetails',
                data: dataString,
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                cache: true,
                success: function(data) 
                {
                 if($.trim(data) === 'error')
                 {
                  alert('yes');   
                 }
                 else
                 {
                  alert('no');
                 }
                },
                error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)                    {
                    console.log("Error connecting to server. " + XMLHttpRequest + ", " + textStatus +", "+ errorThrown);

                }
</script>
```

//My Controller Code

```
 public function viewAttendeesDetails()
{
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');

  $data = array();
  $id = $_POST['id'];


  $AttendeesDetails = $this->model->GetAttendeesDetail($id);
  if($row = $AttendeesDetails->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
  {
    $this->tp->DBToHTMLAll($row, $data);        
  }

    echo json_encode($data);
    exit;
} 

?>
```

//My Model Code

db->prepare("SELECT * FROM crm_contact_list WHERE id = :AttendId");

           $stmt->bindParam(":AttendId", $id);
           $stmt->execute();
           return $stmt;
        } 
        catch (Exception $e) 
        {
            return $e->getMessage();

            return $stmt;
        }
        return;
    }
?>

//Here is the result of console.log(data);

Object
email:"kyle@localhost.com"
full_name:"Test kim"
id:"1"
interest:"Test"
number:"123456"
position:"Prog"
venueID:"1"

Comment: which error are you seeing?

Comment: at a guess ... `$.trim(data) === 'error'` is false - in other words you haven't received as a response the exact word `error`

Comment: even if i dont use $.trim it always go to else statement with alert('no') in it

Comment: What is the actual value of the reponse? You have requested a response type of `data: 'json'`, and so jQuery would expect JSON, parse it for you, and your `data` parameter would be the resulting object - but you are treating `data` like a string.

Comment: can you try `console.log(data);` before `if` condition? May be that will tell you the actual value of the `data`

Comment: @nnnnnn it display via console is a raw json data from database plus it displays via network tab again the data i want to display

Comment: @PratikGaikwad I have tried your suggestion it successfully displays the contents of the data from database but no alerts happened after that

Comment: Please [edit] the question to show a sample of the result. As I already said, you seem to have an object, but you're trying to treat it as a string so that won't work. If you actually show the object's structure we can help further.

Comment: So how can JSON match "error" ?

Comment: @JaromandaX I used $.trim(data) because I thought it might work at first I did is If (data > 0) but again it proceeds to else statement

Comment: @nnnnnn as you suggest here is my controller and my model code

Comment: is the `error` being set from `array()` or `DBToHTMLAll()` functions?

Comment: the easiest way is to place a console.log(data) right before the if and see what is the actual response of the ajax. Also check the id you get on the server side and the echo json_encode($data);

Comment: @PratikGaikwad it displayed the alert yes when I removed ($.trim(data) === 'error') in if statement now when I change ($.trim(data) === 'error') to (data), but my another problem is how to got to else if there is no record.. any Idea?

Comment: @jonystorm please refer to my reply to Pratik just now because I was able to go to if statement block but still goes to if statement even there is no record on the database

Comment: @Kyle, when you use `if(data)` it just checks only if there is any value in `data`. so that will always go in `if` condition rather than `else`. could you please add whatever response being logged in console by `console.log(data)` in the question?

Comment: @PratikGaikwad i have edited my question and included the result of console.log(data) please take note it is same result whether I put console log inside the if statement or before if statement thanks in advance

Comment: @Kyle, okay... now I can say that your `if` statement will never execute... The reason being, as indicated by `nnnnnn`... You are object type is `json` as I said above `(data)` is expected as `object`. so when you are writing `if($trim(data) === 'error)'` it means that its there will be string with `error` in it. Instead you should return proper `stringify`ed JSON which will be parsed as JSON in success function. Let me know if you are still confused.

Comment: @PratikGaikwad I finally solved my own problem by changing the condition in if statement by doing if(data != "") instead of ($trim....) by doing that I was able to display my alert inside if statement and display alert in else statement if there is no record 
again thanks for the efforts guys

Comment: @Kyle, first of all you should use, if I not mistaken in assuming that you have made spelling mistake here, you should use `===`. secondly you should send proper JSON object from `DBToHTMLAll` or `array` functions and do `JSON.parse` in success function with null check before checking for `error`. merely checking `data != ""` will not solve your original or future problems.

Comment: @PratikGaikwad if I use triple equals '===' I got an error in console saying 
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token = so I use double equal and I dont see any error any way thanks again for your advice :)

Answer (score 0):

I would return from your controller something like

`{status: 'success', data: myArrayWithFoundData}`

so when you receive the ajax response you could do a json_decode, and check the status.

So in you controller you would have

```
if($row = $AttendeesDetails->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
      {
          $this->tp->DBToHTMLAll($row, $data);
          $rsp_data = {status: 'success', data: $data};
      }else{
          $rsp_data = {status: 'error', data: null};
      }
echo json_encode($resp_data);
```

Something like that, so in the ajax response you would do a

```
var a = JSON.parse(data);
```

and check the `a.status` for error